# std::ref error in VS2015

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct C
{
    void printMe() const
    {}
};

struct D
{
    void operator()() const
    {}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    std::thread t9(std::ref(d));    // fine
    t9.join();

    C c;
    std::thread t8(&C::printMe, std::ref(c));   // error in VS2015
    t8.join();

/*
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: '_Callable=void (__thiscall C::* )(void) const'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: '_Types={std::reference_wrapper<C>}'
*/
}


http://ideone.com/bxXJem built without problems
```

Is the following code correct?

```
std::thread t8(&C::printMe, std::ref(c));
```

Comment: `std::thread t8(&C::printMe, &c);`

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2219

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't compile. To compile it and make run it you need:

1) It needs to set the method printMe as a static method to send an its address (printMe's address), otherwise you are sending a relative address to instance `C`.

2) At the moment of create the thread `t8`, you are sending a reference to object `C` as an argument but the function `printMe` doesn't have arguments, So you need declare the argument into the printMe method.

3) As @cpplearner told you, send the pointer of the method as: `std::thread t8(&C::printMe, &c);`.

The resulting code is:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct C
{
    static void printMe(C* ref)
    {
        std::cout << "Address of C ref: " << std::hex << ref << std::endl;
    }
};

struct D
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "Operator D" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    std::thread t9(std::ref(d));    // fine
    t9.join();

    C c;
    std::thread t8(&C::printMe, &c);   // Compile in VS2015
    t8.join();

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
}
```

And the output is:

[image]